# Метод imshow с OpenCv открывает много окон, которые создаются с помощью библиотеки mss(она нужна для захвата видео с экрана)

Tags: python, opencv

Но при этом в окне создаются много окон, с захваченным видео, которые уменьшаются в размерах.Что сделать что бы в окне отображалось одно исходное видео с 1 размерностью?Вот код:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

from mss.darwin import MSS


monitor = {
                "left": 100,
                "top": 10,
                "width": 2880,
                "height": 880,
            }
dec = MSS(

)
while True:
    im = dec.grab(monitor=monitor)
    cv2.imshow('окно', np.array(im))
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Должно быть одно окно по идее, по крайней мере в Windows это так, вы вообще читали документацию как работать с OpenCV в вашей операционной системе, не всегда код может быть идентичным.

Comment: Это даже в аналоговой технике было.  Такое бывает, если  камерой снимать монитор, на который выводится картинка с этой камеры.  Странно, что это вызывает удивление и непонимание.